# how to get dictionary source in android apps

Tags: java, android, dictionary, spell-checking

I want to develop an android application that needs an english word dictionary. Can you people tell me any link from where i can have that database containing a reasonable number of english words with their meanings and example sentence.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [dict.org](http://www.dict.org/bin/Dict), which is a great resource for free dictionaries. [Wordnet](http://www.dict.org/bin/Dict?Form=Dict3&Database=wn) should be perfect for your needs.